# execute adb commands in cmd prompt from python script

Tags: python-2.7, adb

I am trying to execute adb commands in an automated way from python script. Please note that I am using python 2.7 in Windows. 
If I manually do it, the sequence is like this:

```
C:\Project\python>adb shell
login:<enter login id e.g. root>
Password: <enter password e.g. test>
Last login: Thu Feb  9 12:29:46 UTC 2017 on pts/0
~ # date
date
Thu Feb  9 12:55:06 UTC 2017
```

I am trying to handle this sequence from python script. I have tried using  subprocess.call("adb shell date") but it fails saying that cannot execute commands without logging in. I am not sure how to to pass the login id and password. Sorry for the noob question, as I am very new to Python.

Appreciate your help guys !!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try `subprocess.Popen`:

```
import subprocess

cmd_input = """<enter login id e.g. root>
<enter password e.g. test>
date"""

process = subprocess.Popen(
    "adb shell",
    shell=True,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)
process.communicate()
for i in cmd_input.split("\n"):
    process.communicate(i + "\n")
```

Or:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(
    "adb shell",
    shell=True,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)
process.communicate(user + "\n")
process.communicate(pwd + "\n")
process.communicate(cmd + "\n")
```

Another option is to use [google/python-adb](https://github.com/google/python-adb) or [adb via pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/adb/1.1.1)

Comment: Just to clarify, comments in <..> are only for representation of what I do manually. I tried    cmd_input = "root test date" and then subprocess.call("adb shell", shell=True, input=cmd_input). But I am getting this error  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "subprocess_login.py", line 4, in <module>
    subprocess.call("adb shell", shell=True, input=cmd_input)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 524, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input'

Comment: @wicked_snail I know, I just copied them over. `input` is my error, I looked at the Python3 documentation.

Comment: I tried user = "root" 
        pwd = "test"
        cmd = "date"  . 
On executing subprocess.Popen("adb shell", shell=True).communicate("{}\n{}\n{}\n".format(user,pwd,cmd)), I get 
C:\Project\MMC\python>python subprocess_login.py
mdm9607 login:

So it is asking to enter the credentials manually. But I want it to login and execute the command from the script.

Comment: I tried the second option, but it hangs after execution. After 60 seconds, it exits from execution. Probably because the login timeout is 60 seconds. If I quit in middle , it gives:   File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 1033, in _communicate
    stdout_thread.join()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 947, in join
    self.__block.wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 339, in wait
    waiter.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: I printed the stdout :  'root\r\r\ntest\r\r\ndate\r\r\nmdm9607 login: \r\r\nLogin timed out after 60 seconds.\r\r\n'

Comment: It stopped for 60 secs and gave this :  File "subprocess_login.py", line 28, in <module>
    process.communicate(pwd + "\n")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 806, in communicate
    return self._communicate(input)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in _communicate
    self.stdin.write(input)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: @wicked_snail I'm sorry, but I don't know any solution. You could give google/python-adb a try.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting below error with `process.communicate('command_to_send\n')`

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Using the subprocess communicate command in below way resolved the TypeError:

```
process.communicate(b'input keyevent KEYCODE_CALL\n')
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that this does only work for Python3, Python2 handles everything as a bytestring (instead of a unicode one) by default.